# Reducing false positive in CNN (Conv1D) text classification model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, keras, convolution

I created a char-based CNN model for text classification on `keras` + `tensorflow` - mainly using Conv1D, mainly based on:

http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

The model is performing very good with 80%+ accuracy on test data set. However I'm having problem with false positive. One of the reason could be that the final layer is a `Dense` layer with `softmax` activation function.

To give an idea of how the model is performing, I train the model with data set with 31 classes with 1021 samples, the performance is ~85% on 25% test data set

However if you include false negative the performance is pretty bad (I didn't run another test data with false negative since it's pretty obvious just testing by hand) - every input has a corresponding prediction. For example a sentence `acasklncasdjsandjas` can result in a class `ask_promotion`.

Are there any best practice on how to deal with false positive in this case?
My idea is to:

1. Implement a `noise` class where samples are just a set of totally random text. However this doesn't seem to help since the noise doesn't contain any pattern thus it would be difficult to train the model
2. Replace softmax with something that doesn't require all output probability to 1 so small values can stay small regardless of other values. I did some research on this but there's not much information on changing the activation function for this specific case

Comment: Can you post the confusion matrix or provide more details on number of classes, class balance, and which classes have false positives (if not all)

Comment: @AhmedS I added more detail as requested into the question.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the issue of *imbalanced data*, where two classes have completely different supports (the number of instances in each class). This issue is particularly crucial in the task of hierarchical classification in which some classes with a deep hierarchy tend to have much more instances than the others.

Anyway, let's simply the issue as binary classification, and name the class with much more support Class-A and the other one with less support Class-B. Generally speaking, there are two popular ways to circumvent this issue.

1. **Under-sampling:** You fix Class-B as is. Then you sample instances from Class-A for the same amount as Class-B. Combine these instances and train your classifier with them.
2. **Over-sampling:** You fix Class-A as is. Then you sample instances from Class-B for the same amount as Class-A. The same goes with Choice 1.

For more information, please refer to this KDNuggets page.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/7-techniques-handle-imbalanced-data.html

Hope this helps. :P

Comment: I'm already doing over-sampling before going through the stratified data split so the data is already well balanced.